# Extracts all .gz files from a directory using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Currently I'm able to extract the .gz file by passing file name in the input. However, I want to extracts all the .gz files that are present in the directory. Kindly review and help with the solution.

Code:

```
input  = "C:\Src_csv\ExtractionFile\Axy.txt.gz"
output = "C:\Src_csv\Extraction\Dest\"

Call Unzip(input, output)

Function UnZip(ByVal input, ByVal output)
    Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    'Set xfolder = objfso.GetFolder(input)

    If oFSO.FileExists("C:\Program files\7-Zip\7Z.exe") Then   'Update the 7zip file path
        s7zLocation = "C:\Program files\7-Zip\"                'Update the 7zip file path
    Else
        UnZip = "Error: Couldn't find 7z.exe"
        Exit Function
    End If
    'Ensure we can find archive to uncompress
    If Not oFSO.FileExists(input) Then
        UnZip = "Error: File Not Found."
        Exit Function
    End If
    For Each
        oShell.Run """" & s7zLocation & "7z.exe"" e -y -o""" & output & _
            """ """ & input & """", 0, True
        UnZip = 1
End Function
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  Do you have a question about a specific problem?  See the [tour] as well as "[ask]" and also "[mcve]".  Also [here is a checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help with posting questions here.

Comment: No need for a loop in your code. Just pass the source directory path into your function and append `\*.gz` when invoking `7z.exe`.